# Toggling between Boolean variable

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering how you would toggle between two boolean variables. This works correctly the first time running the code but then after running it a second time the output isn't correct.

*Output first time running switchPlayer():*

```
player1.isActive = false,
player2.isActive = true
```

*Output second time running switchPlayer():*

```
player1.isActive = true,
player2.isActive = true
```

Below is the code I wrote:

```
var Player = function(score, isActive){
  this.score = score;
  this.isActive = isActive;
}

Player.prototype.toggleIsActive = function(){
      if(this.isActive === false){
        this.isActive = true;
      } else{
        this.isActive = false;
      }
    }

function switchPlayer(){
  if(player1.isActive === true){
    player1.toggleIsActive();
    player2.toggleIsActive();
  } else{
    player1.isActive = true;
  }
}
var player1 = new Player("0", true);
var player2 = new Player("0", false);

switchPlayer();
switchPlayer();
```

Comment: Just call the toggle function for both players. You don't need additional tests inside `switchPlayer()`. Still, I'm wondering why you don't see the problem with your code: if you look at your `switchPlayer` as it is now, you're doing thing A if player 1 is active, and something completely different otherwise. No wonder it won't work. Even as a total beginner one should realize that `player1.toggleIsActive(); player2.toggleIsActive();` is very different from `player1.isActive = true;`

Comment: Also, if you want to switch between true and false, use `myValue = !myValue` -- this will turn a true into a false, or a false into a true.

Answer (score 7):

You can simplify it like this:

```
Player.prototype.toggleIsActive = function(){
   this.isActive = !this.isActive;
}

function switchPlayer(){
    player1.toggleIsActive();
    player2.toggleIsActive();
}
```

ToggleIsActive should just be the opposite of what it once was. Also note that switchPlayer only calls toggle with no specific logic.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by removing the `if/else` from the `switchPlayer()` implementation:

```
function switchPlayer(){

  player1.toggleIsActive();
  player2.toggleIsActive();

}
```

Also, consider simplifying your `toggleIsActive()` method on the `Player` prototype like so:

```
Player.prototype.toggleIsActive = function(){
   this.isActive = !this.isActive;
}
```

Here's a full example:

```js
var Player = function(score, isActive){
  this.score = score;
  this.isActive = isActive;
}

Player.prototype.toggleIsActive = function(){
   this.isActive = !this.isActive;
}

function switchPlayer(){

  player1.toggleIsActive();
  player2.toggleIsActive();
  
}
var player1 = new Player("0", true);
var player2 = new Player("0", false);

console.log('player1.isActive', player1.isActive)
console.log('player2.isActive', player2.isActive)
console.log('----------------')

switchPlayer();

console.log('player1.isActive', player1.isActive)
console.log('player2.isActive', player2.isActive)
console.log('----------------')

switchPlayer();

console.log('player1.isActive', player1.isActive)
console.log('player2.isActive', player2.isActive)
console.log('----------------')
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let player1 = {};
let player2 = {};

player1.isActive = false;
player2.isActive = true;

function toggle () {
  player1.isActive = !player1.isActive;
  player2.isActive = !player2.isActive;
  
  console.log('player1', player1.isActive, 'player2', player2.isActive);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="toggle()">Toggle</button>
```